# One method that can work with both primitive data types and generics?

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I recently learnt about generics and re-wrote my old Binary Sorting program which used to only sort values of type `int`
My new implementation will sort everything except primitive data types.
Below is the implementation:

```
import java.util.Random;

class SortAllTypes
{
    static <All extends Comparable<All>> void sort(All array[])
    {
        for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1]) > 0)
                {
                    All temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;
                }
    }

    static <All> void display(All array[])
    {
        for(All value : array)
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String X[])
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        Integer x[] = new Integer[10];
        String directory[] = {"def", "ghi", "abc"};
        for(int i = 0 ; i < x.length; i++)
            x[i] = generator.nextInt(100);
        sort(directory);
        display(directory);

        sort(x);
        display(x);
    }
}
```

I'm aware that generics don't work with primitive data types and I can't find a solution to write a **single** function that can sort values of any `type`.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not in Java. What you can do is to overload the method and adapt the code accordingly for the desired primary data type(s).

Comment: @thatidiotguy `Integer[]` cannot be autoboxed to `int[]`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, overloading will create more methods defeating the purpose of the question :)

Comment: Looks like you haven't read the first part of my comment: **Not in Java**.

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible to define a method which takes `Object` and then does `instanceof` checks to determine which type of array was provided and operate the specific type of array. I am pretty sure this is not what you are looking for.

Look at the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class. Note that every operation (binarySearch, copyOf, sort, etc.) is overloaded for `Object[]` and every primitive type.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily need to use `instanceof`